# Modal view reappearing after dismissal

Tags: ios, modal-dialog

I am calling a login view modally in the view did load method in the root view controller, but when I dissmiss the modal view controller it just reappears! any suggestions?
hears the code:

** .h **

```
//
//  FirstViewController.h
//  Voyager
//
//  Created by Peter Unger on 9/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Penumbra Software. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface DefaultSettingsViewController :
UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

** .m **

```
//
//  FirstViewController.m
//  Voyager
//
//  Created by Peter Unger on 9/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Penumbra Software. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       }

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    login.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton;
    login.delegate = (id)self;
    login.signUpController.delegate = (id)self;
    [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Bergasms already said, you have a loop. the `viewDidAppear` method is called everytime your viewController appears in the screen. So, when you resign the presented viewController, the first view controller was supposed to appear, calling then the `viewDidAppear`, which will present again the `PFLogInViewController`, creating a loop.

If you move the code to the `viewDidLoad` method, your modal will be called just once, as this method is called only when the viewController is allocated.

And if you want the user to do not see the first viewController, you may want to set the animation in the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` to `NO`.

---

**Edit:**

One person said in another question that you might get an error if you call another view controller inside viewDidLoad (although I have done this once, haven't checked the behavior of the error yet). If that's your case and you get an error, you would have to let the code in `viewDidAppear`.

---

And if somehow you still want use `viewDidAppear`, you can simply create a `BOOL` property that controls if the `PFLogInViewController` was already called or not. It will be something like this

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL isLogged;
```

And

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (!self.isLogged)
    {
        self.isLogged = YES;
        PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        login.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton;
        login.delegate = (id)self;
        login.signUpController.delegate = (id)self;
        [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

In this way, your `PFLogInViewController` will be called once.

Comment: Peter Unger, if you look back and see this, this answer solves the problem just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop there. When the modal controller is dismissed, the viewDidAppear method will be called on first view controller, which will launch the modal view again. You should put comments or break points at the launch code to help debug things like this.

```
@interface FirstViewController (){
BOOL has_shown_login_modal;
}
@end  


 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    has_shown_login_modal = NO;
   }  


 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
   if(!has_shown_login_modal){
      PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
     login.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton |        PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton;
     login.delegate = (id)self;
     login.signUpController.delegate = (id)self;
     [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:nil];
      has_shown_login_modal = YES;
   }
}
```

Comment: So where would you recommend I call the modal view controller?

Comment: You can call it in there, but I am assuming you only want to call it on the first time the view appears. There are numerous ways around this. The easiest is to use a boolean flag. i'll update my answer for you. Note, while this is the simplest, you might need to re-architect your code if it gets more complicated. Having too many boolean flags increases the state space of your app significantly.

Comment: thank you that makes sense, I only have one problem, and that is that on the line:                                                                         `bool has_shown_login_modal;`                                            I am getting the error: Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol     Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: not sure if you have fixed it yet or not, but to declare instance variables up the top there, you need to put them in {}, i will update the answer.